# Alternative to Google Analytics with A/B testing and PDF scheduling

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, analytics, logging, a-b-testing

Is there a hosted solution that competes with Google Analytics and has some of the heavy hitting features:

- A/B testing with regression analysis
- Conversion tracking
- Funnels
- Schedulable reports that email PDF files

Comment: Have you looked at [Omniture](http://www.omniture.com/en/)?

Comment: I haven't used Adobe products in a while, but wow... http://imgur.com/kTb0h I'll check back in a little while, thank you

Comment: Wow, it's not good for an Internet technology customer to have web site problems ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure Omniture is expensive. Google as you know merged their website optimizer with analytics not too long ago. There are few companies that offer both Analytics and Split testing tools. There are plenty of companies who offer one or the other. Clicky Analytics is great, as for a/b testing Google a bit you'll find a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MixPanel](https://mixpanel.com/) is reasonably priced, has an excellent feature set and has emailed reports.